# Found shared references to a collection many to many relation

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have this method:

```
@Override 
public Movie createMovie(Movie movie) {

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    JwtUser user = (JwtUser)authentication.getPrincipal();
    User current_user = userRepository.findOne(user.getId());       

    movieRepository.save(movie);

    userRepository.save(new HashSet<User>(){{
        add(new User(current_user, new HashSet<Movie>(){{
            add(movie);
        }}));
    }});

    return movieRepository.save(movie);
}
```

When I run my application and call that function I get this error:

> Found shared references to a collection: com.movieseat.model.security.User.movies

In my User model I have:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "user_movie",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
)
private Set<Movie> movies;
```

And in my Movie model I have:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "movies", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>(); 

public Set<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}
```

What produces the error?

Comment: Taking into account `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` on users inside the movie entity I would suggest you to try adding a new user to the movie and then store the movie itself. Theoretically, It should store both the movie and the user.

Comment: can you able to post entitys

Comment: why are you saving two times movie? can you show what the new User(current_user, new HashSet<Movie>
code does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I understand your code, you're trying to create a `Movie` in database and bind it to the current `User`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

At first, as you may learn from [Hibernate User Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many-bidirectional), bidirectional @ManyToMany association should be defined and used differently.

> A bidirectional @ManyToMany association has an owning and a mappedBy side. To preserve synchronicity between both sides, it’s good practice to provide helper methods for adding or removing child entities.

Secondly, you should not use `CascadeType.ALL` on `@ManyToMany` associations:

> For @ManyToMany associations, the REMOVE entity state transition
>   doesn’t make sense to be cascaded because it will propagate beyond the
>   link table. Since the other side might be referenced by other entities
>   on the parent-side, the automatic removal might end up in a
>   ConstraintViolationException.
>
> For example, if @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) was defined and
>   the first person would be deleted, Hibernate would throw an exception
>   because another person is still associated with the address that’s
>   being deleted.

So, we should move `cascade` to the owning side, change cascade type, provide helper methods to the `User` and update only the owning side (`User`) of the association in our business logic. Let's change the code.

User model:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinTable(name = "user_movie",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
)
private Set<Movie> movies = new HashSet<>();

public void addMovie(Movie movie) {
    movies.add(movie);
    movie.getUsers().add(this);
}

public void removeMovie(Movie movie) {
    movies.remove(movie);
    movie.getUsers().remove(this);
}
```

Movie model:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "movies")
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
```

And business logic:

```
@Override
public Movie createMovie(Movie movie) {

    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    JwtUser user = (JwtUser)authentication.getPrincipal();
    User current_user = userRepository.findOne(user.getId());

    current_user.addMovie(movie);
    userRepository.save(current_user);

    return movie;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do! Thank you for the explanation and snippets. Things kind of work now. When I create the movie I do create a record in my movie table and in the user_movie but then the application crashes. So I think there's a reference somewhere that causes a infinite loop.` Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.movieseat.model.security.Authority["users"]`

Comment: The problem stated above is resolved when I remove the many to many relation between movies and users.

Comment: Seems like the message converter (MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter, if you respond with JSON) can't convert `Movie` due to the recursive chain Movie -> users -> User -> movies -> etc. Try to mark `User.movies` or `Movie.users` with @JsonIgnore annotation.

Comment: Looks like this is a different issue, the message states: `->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.movieseat.model.security.User["authorities"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]->com.movieseat.model.security.Authority["users"]`  . I'll reward you the answer for this question and the bounty. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, then it's just different entites that have recursive reference chain - User.authorities‌​ and Authority.user‌​s. See [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue) answers. Seems like `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` should handle this as well as `@JsonIgnore`.

Comment: Thanks, that question helped :) Cheers for the help!